# How can I get an image from a protected canvas element using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am trying to get an image from the canvas.

(This is to get the article from https://newslibrary.naver.com/viewer/index.nhn?articleId=1995042000209101001&officeId=00020, but first, click the 'X' button to see the article.)

The HTML codes are like,

```
<p class="main_layer_article_body" data-container="">
    <canvas width="421" height="594" style="touch-action: none; cursor: inherit;">
    </canvas>
</p>
```

Its xpath is `'//*[@id="_textContainer"]/p[2]/canvas'`

Following suggestions from similar questions,

1. I tried taking a screenshot. However, since the image (article) is too long, I have to scroll down. Hence, the screenshot method did not work well.
2. I tried to save the image from the canvas directly.

   ```
   canvas = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_textContainer"]/p[2]/canvas')
   canvas_base64 = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png').substring(21);", canvas)
   output_image = base64.b64decode(canvas_base64)
   with open("image.png", 'wb') as f:
       f.write(output_image)
   ```

But it only returns an all-white image, whose size is about 6KB.

Is there any way I could get the whole image of this canvas (article)?